# Adding custom masking for date formatting

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap, masking

As ng-mask dont work with ngbDatepicker, I make a directive date formatted masking with regex to get user input.
but problem is after entering a date when i press backspace "/" doesn't remove.

what could be best approach to resolve this issue?

My HTML datepicker code:

```
<div class="input-group">
          <input formControlName="DOB" class="form-control" id="DateOfBirthFormat" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="dateOffBirth" ngbDatepicker
            #d="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d.open();" (dateSelect)="chooseDate($event)" (input)="inputDateFRomCalender($event.target.value)" appMaskInput onlyNumbers>
          <span class="input-group-text" (click)="d.open()">
            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
 </div>
```

my directive code:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from 
   '@angular/core';
    @Directive({
    selector: '[appMaskInput]'
   })
  export class MaskInputDirective implements OnInit {

  private regexOne: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d{2}$/);
  private regexTwo: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/);

  private regexThree: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d\/$/);

  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace'];

  @Input() appMaskValue: string;
  constructor(
    private elRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])

  onInput(event) {

    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }


    let v = event.target.value;

    let test = v.keyCode;

    console.log(test);



    if (v.match(this.regexOne) !== null) {
      event.target.value = v + '/';
    } else if (v.match(this.regexTwo) !== null) {
      event.target.value = v + '/';
    }
   

  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this and get it to work?